# What does Server object, Remote object mean in RMI Java?

Tags: java, jndi, rmi, distributed-system

I have been studying for my exams and there is one topic of RMI is inluded in exam.

There are few simple definitions which i could not find online.

Can anybody please briefly describe the following terms used in the RMI architecture:

**Remote object**, **Server object**, **rmiregistry** and **rmic**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: @EJP yes but i don't get the documentation. its very confusing

Comment: The documentation for `rmiregistry` and `rmic` is very confusing? Really? What documentation is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remote object:** it's the object that you want to make "shared".

**Server object:** it's a remote object from a server.

**rmiregistry:** the rmiregistry command creates and starts a remote object registry on the specified port on the current host.

**rmic:** the rmic compiler generates stub and skeleton class files (JRMP protocol) and stub and tie class files (IIOP protocol) for remote objects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but is the definition for Server Object is right?

Comment: 'Server object' and 'remote object' are the same thing. Skeletons have been obsolete for 20 years.

Comment: @EJP exactly they are outdated but i dont know why it is still in our module.

Comment: Yes, they are both remote objects. Is not a bad idea starting by knowing the entire mechanism of RMI, even what is a Skel file and what was used for.

Comment: Thanks @J.Lorenzo . Yes i am learning about RMI but i think no one uses it in the industry, it is just the exam requirement but i am still trying to learn it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @XioNipnang "no-one uses it in the industry": false. I use it.